# Better hashCode function for stock ticker symbols?

Tags: java, hash, hashmap, hashcode

I'm saving stock objects in a `HashMap` where the key is the ticker symbol `String` (e.g. `"AAPL"` for Apple, Inc.).  Unfortunately, this is not viable as Ally Financial Inc (GM1) and Global Partners LP (GLP) have colliding hash codes and will over-write each other. Eg:  `"GM1".hashCode() == "GLP".hashCode()` == major problems.

Is there a `hashCode` for stock ticker strings that can guarantee no collisions?

```
public Class StockTicker {
    public String symbol;

    public StockTicker(String symbol) { this.symbol = symbol; }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        // What goes here?
    }
}
```

Successful answers may take advantage of the fact that the ticker string will have no more than 5 characters, and will be upper-case alpha-numeric with the exception of "." as in "BRK.B".

Comment: if you override hash code, make sure you override equals too.

Comment: It's possible to write a perfect (without collisions for non-equal objects) hashcode, but you do know that HashMap will handle collisions correctly (albeit at a very slight performance hit) even under collisions, yes? Is that bad enough to not just use `return symbol.hashCode();`?

Comment: @Mshnik Do you mean it's **not** possible?

Comment: @christopher, yeah with you on that.  Equals is trivial, so wanted to keep the question focused on the hashCode implementation.

Comment: The default `String.hashCode()` works well if you use no more than 31 consecutive letters e.g. A-Z as this will produce unique values for up to 5 letters as 31^5 < 2^32. The use of a `.` shouldn't cause a great difference.

Comment: Note unless your collection has 2^32 buckets, your hashCode will be reduced. e.g. say you have only 1024 buckets, then the hashCode will be reduce to just 10 bits and you will get collisions even with unique hashCodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the other answers and comments have noted, A) Java will handle collisions correctly assuming you've written equals and hashcode in a agreeable fashion and B) even getting a perfect hashcode function doesn't guarantee that you won't get collisions.

With that said, it is possible to write a perfect hashcode function for your specification. There are exactly 37 characters that you have to worry about (26 letters, 10 digits, and `.`), which is less than 64. Thus we can use 6 bits to represent each character. You have at most `5` characters, which means that your hashcode takes at most 30 bits, which fits within an int.

Here's an implementation that creates that perfect hashcode:

```
  public static class Stock{
    // The possible characters of a stock - note length is < 64
    private final static String alphaNumeric = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890.";

    //Will be 6 for given valid chars, but coding it like this prevents bugs later
    private final static int shiftAmnt = (int)(Math.log(alphaNumeric.length()) / Math.log(2)) + 1;

    private String stock;

    public Stock(String s) {
      stock = s;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
      return o instanceof Stock && stock.equals( ((Stock)o).stock);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
      int code = 0;
      for (char c : stock.toCharArray()) {
        code = code << shiftAmnt;
        code += alphaNumeric.indexOf(c);
      }
      return code;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Good, but because the point of a hash code is to take a "big" object and reduce it to a small unique identifier, is there any point in trying to hash a string of five characters? If a Java character is roughly 2 bytes, than 5 characters is 80 bits (roughly), so hashing at all seems unnecessary in theory.

Comment: (I understand that you're providing this implementation just as an example, not necessarily advocating for its use. You just got be thinking about hash codes and their purpose, so I asked the above question.)

Comment: All true, which is why I raised my earlier comment on the question. He wants a perfect hash function, which is unlikely to reduce the size.

Comment: Hey, I probably am using hashCode() result as the key (I don't have the code in front of me) so it'd be a simple matter to fix.  Still, I appreciate you going the extra mile to answer the question and with bitshifting nonetheless!

Answer (score 4):

I don't think the hashCode of the key strings have any effect on the map itself (I assume you're using the actual ticker symbol string for the key, not the hash code; if you insert into the map using hash codes, then yes, that would cause problems). I ran a quick test, and this runs fine.

```
private Map<String, String> stockMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

@Test
public void mapTest() {
    stockMap.put("GM1", "gm1stock");
    stockMap.put("GLP", "glpstock");

    assertEquals(2, stockMap.size());
}
```

Like Mshnik says, Java will handle the collisions for you, so it's not something you need to worry about. Could you elaborate on what code specifically is causing your problem?